# Dúvidas sobre listagem de dados!

Tags: mysql, mysqli, desempenho, foreach, while

Olá estou desenvolvendo um projeto utilizando a extensão MySQLi, e nisso aproveitando para utilizar algumas funções orientada a objeto! Gostaria de tirar umas dúvidas em relação a listagem de dados, são duas perguntas:

1) Utilizar a função foreach() ao invés de um while() com a função fetch_array() dentro, tem uma listagem mais rápida ou mais lenta? Pois com ambas consigo trazer os dados, No momento estou utilizando a foreach por ser mais rápida de se digitar.

2) Utilizo muitas listagens de tabelas diferentes na mesma página sempre chamando um novo SELECT, seria melhor criar uma função com um SELECT dentro para eu sempre reutiliza-lá ou não iria mudar muita coisa em questão de desempenho?

um exemplo de função para consultas:

https://www.codigofonte.com.br/codigos/funcao-para-consulta-a-banco-de-dados-mysql-no-php

Agradeço qualquer informação.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo cada questão:

1) Minha sugestão é utilizar o que faz mais sentido para cada contexto.

Exemplo: se vc tem uma lista de objetos e quer pegar atributos para expor, utilizar o while não deixa isso de forma tão clara em sua declaração, porém isso se encaixa perfeitamente no que se propõe o foreach.

2) Acredito que tirar as consultas de diretamente da página pode ser bom para limpar e separa o trabalho, porém unificar as consultas tendo em vista que são de tabelas distintas teria que se pensar como um ORM, pela possibilidade de variedade numa consulta.

Comment: Olá, não sei se consegui te passar a minha dúvida em relação a questão 2, editei a postagem e coloquei um link, você acha que se eu sempre chamar uma função (como a do link) que faz um SELECT ao invés de sempre criar um SELECT manualmente sem a função seria mais rápido em questão de desempenho? Ou teoricamente estou chamando um novo SELECT da mesma forma dentro da função?

Comment: Opa @CaioLourençon você ainda continua realizando os vários SELECT e os chamando novamente, essa solução vai deixar o código mais organizado que acredito ser uma vantagem dependendo do contexto.